# Who are these mathematicians in the photos?

Tags: math-history

[image][image]

These pictures are at my university's math lounge, specifically the combinatorics and optimization department.

Edit: It might help to mention that this is at the University of Waterloo, in Canada.

Comment: I think Erdos is at top right.

Comment: @Ranc yes that's him

Comment: Presumably, you've already got Julius Peterson. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julius_Petersen

Comment: Did you try asking the department secretaries or even some of the nearby professors? They probably know

Comment: Would be hilarious if the bottom picture was the math professor at school or the dean.

Comment: Perhaps with some image editing and cropping, you might have success with a reverse image search? (Assuming the last one is also a famous mathematician).

Comment: The third looks familiar, but I think that's because it looks like a generic "author" photo on the back of a book.

Comment: Unlikely that I'm right, but maybe it's [William Tutte](https://alumni.hillsroad.ac.uk/news/alumni-stories/22/Remembering-Bill-Tutte)? He's on their [department homepage](https://uwaterloo.ca/combinatorics-and-optimization/about) ... EDIT: never mind, there is basically no resemblance

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee good call, I believe it is definitely Tutte. Check out the picture of him playing chess halfway down this page: http://www.newmarketlhs.org.uk/personalities5.htm